# Can I use ActiveMQ to communicate between two machines not on the same local network?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm developing a project where the front end will be developed on one machine, and the backend on another. Can I use ActiveMQ to send messages between these 2 machines online? That is the machines have an internet connection, but are not on the same network (e.g. each machine is in a country, and has a wifi connection). If this is possible, how can it be done? If not, are there alternatives that accomplish the same objective?

Comment: Messaging is a good option when passing data across networks, since it handles varying network speed and disconnection better than other computer-to-computer connectivity which relies on the code to handle errors and retries.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what your specific constraints will result in for network connectivity. In any event, regardless of the topology, technology, etc. if two machines can communicate with each other over a network connection then they can use ActiveMQ.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better if you make the front end calling REST or GraphQL API in your back end rather than ActiveMQ. And it's totally possible if one machine can connect to another.

What you need to do here is to get the public IP address of the machine either via port forwarding if it's machine in your home/friend home. Normally people use some public cloud services these day to get virtual cloud machine and the cloud provider will give you the IP address

Comment: Borderline -1 here.. REST and GraphQL require the code to handle disconnect, network down, network slow, etc type issues. What the poster is describing is pretty close to text-book use case for messaging, such as ActiveMQ